# Get the best offer MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database

I need the highest/best offer from this table by shop!

```
offer    |    f_shop  | price
5253          100       10   
5254          101       12
5255          101       16
5256          102       25
5257          102       11
5258          100       36
```

What is the best way to get the highest offer by shop?
Group by and max() don't give me the correct result.

---

OK, I'm sorry that my question wasn't precise enough.

Here is my actual query:

```
SELECT s.ch_f1 shop, a.ch_f3 price,a.bool_f11 currency,aa.priority AS priority FROM offers a LEFT JOIN shops s ON a.ch_f5=s.extern_id LEFT JOIN offertypes aa ON a.f_offertype=aa.id WHERE 
s.bool_f1=1 AND 
a.bool_f1=1 AND 
a.bool_f4=0
ORDER BY priority ASC, price DESC, currency
```

This is the result:

```
shop; price; currency; priority
Shop A  100.00  1   1
Shop B  50.00   1   1
Shop C  50.00   1   1
Shop D  50.00   1   1
Shop E  50.00   1   1
Shop B  50.00   1   1
Shop A  50.00   1   1
Shop F  40.00   1   1
Shop G  40.00   1   1
Shop H  40.00   1   1
Shop B  39.00   1   1
Shop B  35.00   1   1
Shop B  33.00   1   1
Shop A  30.00   2   1
Shop A  30.00   2   1
Shop X  30.00   2   1
Shop Y  30.00   2   1
Shop Z  30.00   2   1
Shop Q  30.00   2   1
```

But I want to have the best offer from all available shops.
And I need the order value too.
I have no idea how I can do this.

Comment: What was your group by/max() query that went wrong?

Comment: Post the query which does not worked and be more specific to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.6.4. The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want the highest offer for a given shop you can do this:

```
select max(offer) from yourtable where f_shop = 100;
```

Comment: Substitute max for min for the inverse. I.e lowest price.

Comment: I don't know but seems these are the offer id may be he want max by price

Comment: @shakti you don't know then why comment?

Comment: @pradeep: I don't know that's why I commented

Comment: @Shakti the question states "What is the best way to get the highest offer by shop". I assumed in my answer that the OP knows how to ask a question and that's why I answered what I did.

Answer (score 0):

may be you are looking for this

```
select * from table group by f_shop having max(price)
```

will give all the shops row with maximum price.